# Confusion on import and how to use it

Tags: python, python-import

I'm new to python and I have some confusion in the import methods.

I thought that if I do:

```
from tkinter import *
```

I should be able to use:

```
filedialog.askopenfilename
```

However, it gives an error saying unsolved references.

If I do:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
filedialog.askopenfilename
```

It works correctly and I get why it does it. However, I don't understand why Python will not let me do `filedialog.askopenfilename` with `from tkinter import *`

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](https://medium.com/@s16h/importing-star-in-python-88fe9e8bd4d2) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) to get some more insight on how `from <foo> import *` works.

There is two different kinds of `from` targets: modules and packages.

- A **module** is a single python file. If you `import *` from a module, it imports everything, except private names starting with '_'.
- A **package** is a folder, like [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). If you `import *` from a package, it imports all the names that exist in its `__init__.py`. If `__init__.py` does not exist, it imports nothing.

In both cases, the behaviour of `import *` can be overridden by defining `__all__`.

tkinter is a folder(=package) and does not define `__all__` in its `__init__.py`, so `from tkinter import *` only imports the names in its `__init__.py`, like `Tk`, `Button` or `Label`, but not `filedialog`.

Comment: I have a follow up question.  From the python document it says if _ _all_ _ is not defined it will not import submodules but "imports whatever names are defined in the package". Does it mean like "def something()" that is not private inside the _ _init_ _.py will be imported? Also does 'class hi:  def hello()' counts as a submodule inside _ _ init _ _.py?

Comment: The details and exceptions can be read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package). Yes, I think everything that is defined inside the `__init__.py` will be imported. No, a class is not a submodule. You cannot import functions of classes, only the entire class at once.

Comment: oh thx. and this is continuation of my question. If I do `from tkinter import *` I was able to use Tk(), Label(),Button() etc. modules without adding anything infront of it.  However, I could not find them declared inside the `__init__.py`. So in this case how is it working?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about? They are all declared in `__init__.py`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py

Comment: oh I thought the modules where written as `button.py` in the script. The `class button(Widget)` was the modules that were declared. And one very last question. How do I identify submodules in `__init.py__`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'identify submodules' :/

Comment: `from tkinter import *; a = Tk()` works, so can you clarify what you mean by "if you import * from a package (like tkinter), it imports nothing"

Comment: I'll correct, it imports only the definitions of `__init__.py`. I adjust my answer.

Comment: oh the submodules are created using folders and not inside a single py script. That was were I was lost. So if I create a new folder(is this subpackage?) inside a main folder(package) and create a .py script, then that will be a submodule. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: If you create a folder, you create a *package*. The package then can contain several *modules* (python files), or more *sub-packages* (folders). `import` does not directly show whether you are importing a package or module, the command is the same for both.